# Simple Django Model (Add to Cart)

Tags: django

This is my first Django project and I am trying to implement add-to-cart features.

What changes should I make in this model so that multiple "Item" can be added into "Order", and also keep track of item quantity?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    ordered_item = models.ForeignKey('OrderQuantity', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=3)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='images/')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OrderQuantity(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Item')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `ManyToManyField` in Order Model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    ordered_item = models.ForeignKey('OrderQuantity', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

Then you can add items to order in this way:
`someorder.items.add(someItem)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ManyToManyField` in your Item Model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order)
    ---
```

So one item have many orders. You can access it by `order.item_set` or `item.orders`

Comment: Appreciate it. But I do have another question - Can I also keep track of item quantity? When a customer ordered a product, he can specify the quantity he/she wants.

Comment: Yest that's also totally possible. All you have to do is just add `quantity` in `Order`

Comment: Better to put `items` in `Order` model. We think about `order` having attached `items`, not about `items` assigned to `orders`. Than You can simple type `order.items` to get all items related to the `order`.

Comment: Which data types is appropriate in that case? I can think of any because, imagine there are multiple "Items" in same order, say a user wants 1 orange and 2 apples.

Comment: Oops sorry. Actually better write this quantity in Item itself.

Comment: Yes, results the same but it is simpler to think in way I write (based on Django Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your Item model is.

If Item is contains a type of product - you may want to use many-to-many field in your Order model, like so:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    ...
```

If Item describes one real item (not type of items), the proper way would be using ForeignKey in your Item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    ...
```